# Is there a way to properly parse an enum parameter into a method dynamically invoked

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

imagine the following problem:

```
//Assembly 1
namespace R {
    public class Remote
    {
        public enum SomeTypes
        {
            A = 12,
            B = 14,
            C = 16
        }
        
        public void DoSomething(SomeTypes s, int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((int)s * a);
        }
    }
}

//Assembly 2

namespace L
{
    public class Local
    {
        public enum SomeTypes
        {
            A = 12,
            B = 14,
            C = 16
        }
        
        public Local()
        {
            assembly = ....;
            
            dynamic instance = assembly.DefinedTypes.First(t => t.GetName() == "R.Remote").GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object [] {});
            
            instance.DoSomething(SomeTypes.A,3); //this is where it crashes because of an argument mismatch, fair point: One is R.Remote.SomeTypes the other one L.Local.SomeTypes
            instance.DoSomething((int)SomeTypes.A,3); //this should work technically, does not, one is R.Remote.SomeTypes the other one int, despite the fact that they can be converted into each other
            instance.DoSomething((dynamic)SomeTypes.A,3); //just a hacky guess, but this does not work either
        }

    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to call DoSomething(...), without the argument mismatch exception triggering?

Just in case: I can't access the Remote assembly.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: `Remote.SomeTypes` is a `public` enum, so why redefine this in your local assembly?

Comment: What do you mean you "can't access the Remote assembly"? You're calling `DoSomething()` from it so it seems like you can access it just fine. Do you mean you can't modify the code in that assembly? Is `Remote` a plug-in or something? I was wondering why you're loading it at runtime instead of just adding it as a reference. Now I'm slightly confused too.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay cause OP is slightly confused =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the type via reflection for some reason, you can continue using it to get needed enum value and call method:

```
var remoteType = typeof(Remote); //you remote type from assembly
// you will use var remoteType = assembly.DefinedTypes.First(t => t.GetName() == "R.Remote");
var method = remoteType.GetMethod("DoSomething"); // find needed method somehow
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(remoteType); // creates instance via parameterless ctor
var remoteSomeType = remoteType.GetNestedType("SomeTypes"); // get Remote.SomeType
var a = remoteSomeType.GetField("A").GetValue(null); // Get Remote.SomeType.A enum value
method.Invoke(instance, new object[]{a, 3}); // call method
```

Note that in general dynamic/reflection is slow, so if you are planning to invoke this method frequently you should think about "caching" reflection somehow, for example trying to compile it using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).

Comment: @slightlyconfused glad it helped!